# Why the Expands/Collapse panes button is not shown in the inspector tab

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I have noticed that since version 57 of firefox the expand/collapse panes button is not shown anymore in the inspector tab. The dropper button appears instead. Any idea how to restate it

Here a firefox 59.1 screenshot[image]

An here is the expand/collapse panes button

[image]

This is the state of inspector sidebar when `devtools.inspector.split-sidebar-toggle` is applied, this actually add the expand/collapse button but the behaver is not the expected

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some screenshot?

Comment: I just added an screen-shot, the same happen in firefox 57/58...

Comment: I'm sorry, what you mean by `expand/collapse panes button`? I'm was looking for answer for this, that's why I asked for screenshot

Comment: If you check the debugger tab you will see a couple of them. I updated the question to show an image

Comment: I see, now I know what you mean and I found the answer that you can see in my posted answer, right below

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the button has been removed in recent version(s) of Firefox, I don't know why.

I created [bug 1449119](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1449119) and asking to bring back the button again.

For now you can enable the button using following steps (*Firefox v59.x*):

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `devtools.inspector.split-sidebar-toggle`
3. Double-click on that (*to toggle the value*)
4. Done!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but `devtools.inspector.split-sidebar-toggle` implements a different behaver, what it does is to split the rules panel, I updated the question in order to show the state of inspector panel when `devtools.inspector.split-sidebar-toggle` is applied

Comment: You right, seems like CSS pane/rules is not hidden-able.

Comment: At this point it seems that we can only wait for an answer on the ticket